# How can I write BigQuery SQL to group data by start and end date of column changing?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
ID|FLAG|TMST
1|1|2022-01-01
1|1|2022-01-02
...(all dates between 01-02 and 02-05 have 1, there are rows for all these dates)
1|1|2022-02-15
1|0|2022-02-16
1|0|2022-02-17
...(all dates between 02-17 and 05-15 have 0, there are rows for all these dates)
1|0|2022-05-15
1|1|2022-05-16
```

->

```
ID|FLAG|STRT_MONTH|END_MONTH
1|1|202201|202202
1|0|202203|202204
1|1|202205|999912
```

I have the first dataset and I am trying to get the second dataset.  How can I write bigquery SQL to group by the `ID` then get the start and end month of when a flag changes? If a specific month has both `0,1` flag like month 202202, I would like to consider that month to be a `1`.

Comment: the expected output is not consistent with the data sample. How do you get `1|0|202203|202204`? Share a usable data sample and consistent expected results.

Comment: @Horaciux Because `202202` contains a 1 and 0 it defaults to being part of the `1` grouping instead of the `0` grouping.  So the `0` grouping starts at `202203` instead of `202202`

Comment: but there is no row for month 4, what is the rule there?

Comment: ```
1|0|2022-02-17
...(same for next days)
1|0|2022-05-15
```

This means that all dates between those values will have value of 0. (so month 3 and 4)

Comment: that is my point, there is no flag change in April, why is an end date in expected results?

Comment: I have updated original post, let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: so, you do not need start and end date, you need to know if there was a change between  pair of months?

Comment: You can think of it like that, yes.  A change of flag between months, where a switch from 1->0 would be considered starting at the next month (because if a month ever contains 1 that entire month would be in the 1 flag grouping - which is why the switch on 2-15 to 2-16 is considered as 0 starting on 202203 in the output dataset, the only case this wouldn't be true is if the switch happened between the last day of a previous month and the start of a new month, because the new month wouldn't have any 1 flags in it). But a switch from 0->1 would be considered the month where it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below *gaps and islands* approach.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 flag, DATE '2022-01-01' tmst UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 1 flag, '2022-01-02' tmst UNION ALL
-- (all dates between 01-02 and 02-05 have 1, there are rows for all these dates)
  SELECT 1 id, 1 flag, '2022-02-15' tmst UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 0 flag, '2022-02-16' tmst UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 0 flag, '2022-02-17' tmst UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 0 flag, '2022-03-01' tmst UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 0 flag, '2022-04-01' tmst UNION ALL
-- (all dates between 02-17 and 05-15 have 0, there are rows for all these dates)
  SELECT 1 id, 0 flag, '2022-05-15' tmst UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 id, 1 flag, '2022-05-16' tmst
),
aggregation AS (
  SELECT id, DATE_TRUNC(tmst, MONTH) month, IF(SUM(flag) > 0, 1, 0) flag 
    FROM sample_table
   GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT id, ANY_VALUE(flag) flag,
       MIN(month) start_month, 
       IF(MAX(month) = ANY_VALUE(max_month), '9999-12-01', MAX(month)) end_month 
  FROM (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(gap), COUNTIF(gap) OVER w1 AS part FROM (
      SELECT *, flag <> LAG(flag) OVER w0 AS gap, MAX(month) OVER w0 AS max_month
        FROM aggregation
      WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month)
    ) WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month)
  )
 GROUP BY 1, part;
```

**Query results**

[image]